# Convert UTCTime to CSV field with Haskell/cassava

Tags: sqlite, csv, haskell

I started learning Haskell and I try to query data from a SQLite file and dump it again as CSV. I have an issue formating `UTCTime` fields, so that `cassava` can format it correctly. This is my type:

```
    module History.Types
      (Visit)
      where

    import Data.ByteString as B
    import Data.Csv
    import Data.Text (Text)
    import Data.Time
    import Data.Time.Format
    import Database.SQLite.Simple.FromRow

    data Visit = Visit
      { url :: Text
      , title :: Text
      , visit_count :: Int
      , typed_count :: Int
      , last_visit_time :: UTCTime
      , visit_time :: UTCTime
      , from_visit :: Int
      }
      deriving (Show)

    instance FromRow Visit where
      fromRow = Visit <$> field
                      <*> field
                      <*> field
                      <*> field
                      <*> field
                      <*> field
                      <*> field

    instance ToField UTCTime where
      toField t = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S" t

    instance ToRecord Visit where
      toRecord (Visit url
                      title
                      visit_count
                      typed_count
                      last_visit_time
                      visit_time
                      from_visit) = record [ toField visit_time
                                           , toField url
                                           , toField title
                                           , toField visit_count
                                           , toField typed_count
                                           , toField from_visit
                                           , toField last_visit_time
                                           ]
```

And my SQLite code:

```
    {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

    module History.DB
      (queryHistory)
      where

    import History.Types (Visit)

    import Data.Text (Text)
    import Database.SQLite.Simple (open, query_, close, Query)

    q :: Query
    q = "\
    \SELECT urls.url \
    \     , urls.title \
    \     , urls.visit_count \
    \     , urls.typed_count \
    \     , datetime(urls.last_visit_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch','localtime') \
    \     , datetime(visits.visit_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch','localtime') \
    \     , visits.from_visit \
    \FROM urls, visits \
    \WHERE urls.id = visits.id \
    \ORDER BY visits.visit_time"

    queryHistory :: FilePath -> IO [Visit]
    queryHistory dbPath =
      do conn <- open dbPath
         history <- query_ conn q
         close conn
         return history
```

Compiling this code leads to the following error:

```
    src/History/Types.hs:34:15:
        Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘ByteString’
          Expected type: Field
          Actual type: String
        In the expression:
          formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S" t
        In an equation for ‘toField’:
          toField t = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S" t
```

So clearly I make a mess with when formatting the date type into a string. I look at the type information of [`formatTime`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/time/Data-Time-Format.html) and don't really understand why my `String` (I assume the error relates to the date formatting string) has to be a `ByteString`. So my questions are:

1. Is the error related to the time formatting string, and if yes, why is a regular string not working?
2. Is this the right way to format date types to be written to a CSV file using `cassava`?

Comment: Google just for `Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘ByteString’`.`ByteString` isn't a `String`, but conversion utilities exist.

Comment: Note that instanciating `ToField UTCTime` is not recommended in package as it's an `orphan instance` and will leak in everywhere.

Comment: @mb14, I *think* I half understand the issue of orphan instances. My little script reads data from a SQLite file, runs a serious of transformations and dumps it again in CSV format. Does this mean, to prevent orphan instances, I have to define different types for every stage and convert between the types? Or how else should I convert dates to strings than instantiating `ToField UTCTime`?

Comment: The problem of `orphan instance` is if you need write another script similar but uses a different format for date (and therefore define a difference instace of `ToField UTC` )and then you decide to write a 3rd script which uses both, (let's say you need to read two csv and join them) then the `ToField UTCTime` instances of both file will collide and there is no way resolve this collision. How to avoid it ? Just a write a date function conversion somewhere and use it directly in your `fromRow` definition : `fromRow = Visit <$> field <*> fieldDate <*> field ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-} in your History.Types file?  Not sure if that would work, but maybe worth a try.

ToField has to return a ByteString because it returns a Field, and a Field IS a ByteString:

http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-2.17/cassava-0.4.3.0/Data-Csv.html#t:Field

You are calling formatTime correctly, its just that formatTime returns a String and not a ByteString.

You can directly convert with [fromString or pack](http://www.stackage.org/lts-2.17/hoogle?q=String%20-%3E%20ByteString).  So just call formatTime like you are now and convert the result.

Comment: Thanks @Bzzt, that helped a lot. I didn't have to enable the `OverloadedStrings` Language extension but converting the `String` to a `ByteString` worked. I added the import: `import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack)` and changed the instance to `toField t = pack $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S" t`. Great.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `toField` has the signature `a -> Field`. If you look at the `Field` type its definition is `type Field = ByteString`. The result of `formatTime` is a `String`. So the problem is that you provide a `String` where a `ByteString` is expected.

Since `String` is a very common type the first thing you should do is to check if there is already an instance for `ToField String` you can use. If you look at [the definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Csv.html#t:ToField) there is. This means that you can specialize the `toField` function to have the signature `String -> Field` and the use it like this:

```
instance ToField UTCTime where
      toField = toField . formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Thanks @Reite. It's my first time using a strictly typed language, it still is quite mind boggling to me. You solution feels very elegant.